postfix server, cyrus, tls. Authentication failed but testsaslauthd OK
Good afternoon community,
I'm trying to setup postfix server with cyrus and TLS
OS:RHEL 7.7
postfix version: 2.10.1
cyrus version: cyrus-sasl-2.1.26-24
The authentication part looks OK as testsaslauthd is green
bash$ testsaslauthd -u xxxx -p yyyy
0: OK "Success."

The TLS part looks OK too (journalctl -u postfix) when I execute openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -starttls smtp
Dec 30 18:01:49 xxx postfix/smtpd[114933]: Anonymous TLS connection established from localhost[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Dec 30 18:01:49 hp618srv postfix/smtpd[114933]: xsasl_cyrus_server_create: SASL service=smtp, realm=(null)

But when I try to authenticate I have the failure
EHLO myclient
250-server.domain
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH SCRAM-SHA-1 GSS-SPNEGO GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH PLAIN AHVic2Z4X3BhYwBwYWNfdWJzZnge=
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

the encrypted value is generated with
printf '\0%s\0%s' xxxx yyyy| openssl base64

At this stage I'm lost and looking for help to solve it. Looking at the end of journalctl I don't see any that could help me with my current knowledges
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: < localhost[127.0.0.1]: EHLO 127.0.0.1
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: match_list_match: localhost: no match
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: match_list_match: 127.0.0.1: no match
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-serverxxx.xxx.xxx.com
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-PIPELINING
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-VRFY
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-ETRN
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-AUTH SCRAM-SHA-1 GSS-SPNEGO GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250-8BITMIME
Dec 30 18:22:56 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250 DSN
Dec 30 18:23:08 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: < localhost[127.0.0.1]: AUTH PLAIN AHVic2Z4X3BhYwBwYWNfdWJzZng=
Dec 30 18:23:08 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: xsasl_cyrus_server_first: sasl_method PLAIN, init_response AHVic2Z4X3BhYwBwYWNfdWJzZng=
Dec 30 18:23:08 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: xsasl_cyrus_server_first: decoded initial response
Dec 30 18:23:08 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Dec 30 18:23:08 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: warning: localhost[127.0.0.1]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 30 18:23:08 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: smtp_get: EOF
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: match_hostname: localhost ~? 10.14.24.128/25
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 10.14.24.128/25
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: match_hostname: localhost ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: lost connection after AUTH from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: master_notify: status 1
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: connection closed
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx postfix/smtpd[133362]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
Dec 30 18:23:10 serverxxx autoengine[137066]: user xxx from 10.14.43.53: as xxx: 1264  30/12/24 18:22:48 openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:25 -starttls smtp

My cyrus congfiguration file /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf contains
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login

My postfix configuration file /etc/postfix/main.cf contains
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certs/postfix.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/certs/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1

smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_sasl_mechanism_filter = PLAIN, LOGIN
#broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf

Any tips/advices to resolve this is highly appreciated.
I don't know which log I should look at to find valuable information and/or log level to increase to find the root cause
I thank you all in advance


Do you have any logs from saslauthd? What backend is it configured to use? 2) Often Postfix is paired with Dovecot for POP/IMAP – have you considered using Dovecot SASL instead?


Try LOGIN method. Also notice that your base64 value contains your password in plaintext. Don't forget to change it! // @gravity Postfix natively supported Cyris SASL since eternity and only added Dovecot much later, in part because Dovecot implemented it much later. Cyrus SASL itself and its support in Postfix is certainly much more mature and stable and less error-prone.

Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov,
I tried with LOGIN instead of PLAIN but without success. Nevetheless looking at the output of journal -eu postfix I can see my username and password are decyphered correctly
xsasl_cyrus_server_next: decoded response: xxxx  xsasl_cyrus_server_next: decoded response: yyyy
So it's not a bad credentials issue
On the other hand I started saslauthd on the foreground with -d and during the authentication failure nothing is displayed in the terminal so it looks like it didn't reach the authentication layer

Oh, I missed that from the start. cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf is incorrect setting. It should be only path where it lives, not the full name of the config file. The accepted answer to the question to which I marked this as a duplicate explains that in detail.

Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov, your tips helped me fix my issue

postfix configuration was incorrect (thanks Nikita for the link)
My working setup is

File /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login

File /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certs/postfix.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/certs/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tlssmtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/sasl2_loglevel = 1
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1


